# Rails Grape API Endpoint optional params validation in update

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails, null, controller

I have the following rails grape api endpoint in the users resource:

```
    desc 'updates a user'
    params do
      optional :first_name, type: String
      optional :active, type: Boolean
      optional :second_name, type: String
      optional :rating, type: Integer
      requires :id, type: Integer
    end
    put ':id' do
      user = User.find_or_create_by(id: params[:id])
      user.name = params[:name] if params[:name].present?
      user.active = params[:active] if params[:active].present?
      user.second_name = params[:second_name] if params[:second_name].present?
      user.rating = params[:rating] if params[:actratingve].present?
      user.save!
    end
```

Any nicer way to update model without asking per line if the param is present?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
user.assign_attributes(params)
user.save
```

model.assign_attributes(hash) allows you to assign a key value hash to your ActiveRecord object. The only caveat is that the keys passed must correspond to your columns or an exception will be raised. You will need to call .save to persist the changes.

If you want to assign and save in one fell stroke, use model.update(hash).

http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/AttributeAssignment.html

Comment: I did upvote your answer, but you could add a bit of text to add a bit of meat to your answer. This is not Stakc Overlfow, we really to help OP and others readers to improve. You probably should mention what `assign_attributes` so reader can have it directly in your answer do not needs to read the doc.